# Refreshing/deleting markers on Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm showing Google Maps with the current user's location on my website (then, I'll add other features) by using a marker. I'm able to do it: each time the user moves, another marker is inserted on the new position of the user on the map, BUT the previous marker is not removed, so I'm adding more and more markers and I can't delete the previous one before refreshing user's position. I've tried to use timers and other strategies without success: marker.setVisible(false), marker.setMap(null).

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <title>Geolocation</title>

    <style>
      body,html {height:100%}
      #map {width:100%;height:100%;}
    </style>

    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

    <script>  
      var map;

      function initGeolocation() {
        if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {

        var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {enableHighAccuracy:true,timeout:5000,maximumAge:0});

        } else {
          console.log('Geolocation not suported');
        }
      }

      function errorCallback() {}

      function successCallback(position) {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        if(map == undefined) {
          var myOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          }
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        }

        else map.panTo(myLatlng);

        markerUser = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          icon: 'img/iconFox.png',
          title:"You're here!"
        });        
    }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body onload="javascript:initGeolocation()">
    <div id="map">
    </div>    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: First off, its `marker.setMap(null);`, make sure you are reading documentation *thoroughly* before posting here.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, but it was a typo. Of course, I've used marker.setMap(null). I've corrected the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your marker variable in the global scope (where you define your `map` variable), if the marker already exists, move it, otherwise, create it.

```
if (markerUser && markerUser.setPosition) {
    // marker exists, move it
    markerUser.setPosition(myLatlng);
} else { // create the marker
    markerUser = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        icon: 'img/iconFox.png',
        title: "You're here!"
    });
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var markerUser;

function initGeolocation() {
  if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {

    var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    });

  } else {
    console.log('Geolocation not suported');
  }
}

function errorCallback() {}

function successCallback(position) {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  if (map == undefined) {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 18,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  } else map.panTo(myLatlng);
  if (markerUser && markerUser.setPosition) {
    // marker exists, move it
    markerUser.setPosition(myLatlng);
  } else { // create the marker
    markerUser = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png',
      title: "You're here!"
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initGeolocation);
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map">
```

Comment: Your comments should be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Following [tutorial from Google Map JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove). You should create functions for `add`, `remove` marker as you wish:

```
        //Create array of markers as global variable
        var markers = [];

        //And when you add marker onto your map, you push them into array
        markerUser = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          icon: 'img/iconFox.png',
          title:"You're here!"
        });
        markers.push(markerUser);

       // Sets the map on all markers in the array.    
        function setMapOnAll(map) {
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(map);
          }
        }

        // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array. It will hide all markers.
        function clearMarkers() {
          setMapOnAll(null);
        }

        // Shows any markers currently in the array.
        function showMarkers() {
          setMapOnAll(map);
        }

        // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
        function deleteMarkers() {
          clearMarkers();
          markers = [];
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Neo! OK, now I've inserted these 4 functions inside the script of my code. Now I have to call the deleteMarkers() on an array of markers. However, user's position is not an array of markers, bus just a single marker. So I should create an array of markers with only one position (the marker), and I should do arrayOfMarkers.deleteMarkers(), right? Where should I implement that action?
Thanks again!